# JavaScript click event for any google maps markers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, jquery-gmap3

I need to make something happen when any google maps marker is clicked on. Im using the demo from this link as a starting point:

http://gmap3.net/examples/tags.html

UPDATE - ive tried the following:

```
$.each(markers, function(i, marker){
  marker.click(function(){  
     alert('alert');
  });
});

$.each(markers, function(i, marker){
  $(marker).click(function(){  
     alert('alert');
  });
});
```

UPDATE Ive tried adding this middle section to existing code:

```
        $.each(markers, function(i, marker){
            marker.setMap( checked ? map : null);

           //added code begins
            $(marker).click(function(){ 
                 alert('dfd');
              });
           //added code ends

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the OP is asking about doing this using the GMAP3 library, which is a jQuery plugin library that adds an API layer on top of the Google Maps layer.  it is absolutely correct to say that the Google API is to use google.maps.addListener, but I think that the OP wants something that's closer to the [GMAP3 example using addMarkers](http://gmap3.net/api/add-markers.html), but listening to the click event.  With that in mind, I modified the example from GMAP3 and changed the mouseenter event to the click event and got rid of the mouseleave event.

For those wanting to do further playing, I created a [jsFddle of this example](http://jsfiddle.net/lightningwhelk/TxmC5/).

Here's the source:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
     #map {
      width: 400px;
      height: 400px;
  }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">  </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://gmap3.net/js/gmap3-4.1-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#map').gmap3({
            action: 'init',
            options: {
                center: [46.578498, 2.457275],
                zoom: 5
            }
        }, {
            action: 'addMarkers',
            markers: [
            {
                lat: 48.8620722,
                lng: 2.352047,
                data: 'Paris !'},
                {
                    lat: 46.59433,
                    lng: 0.342236,
                    data: 'Poitiers : great city !'},
                    {
                        lat: 42.704931,
                        lng: 2.894697,
                        data: 'Perpignan ! <br> GO USAP !'}
                        ],
                        marker: {
                            options: {
                                draggable: false
                            },
                            events: {
                                click: function(marker, event, data) {
                                    var map = $(this).gmap3('get'),
                                    infowindow = $(this).gmap3({
                                        action: 'get',
                                        name: 'infowindow'
                                    });
                                    if (infowindow) {
                                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                                        infowindow.setContent(data);
                                    } else {
                                        $(this).gmap3({
                                            action: 'addinfowindow',
                                            anchor: marker,
                                            options: {
                                                content: data
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
});​
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" style="width: 400x; height: 400px"></div>​
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're right, the Fiddle no longer functions.  I'll have to see what changed, perhaps need to update to a newer GMAP3.

Answer (score 3):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

});
```

ref: https://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/events.html#UIEvents

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/diode/yXQwp/

Comment: Newbie question but I cant see where to add this in the demo I linked to in my question.

Answer (score 0):

your question really doesn't entail much detail, but maybe you need something like this:

```
$.each(markers, function(i, marker){
  marker.click(function(){  //maybe, its $(marker).click
     console.log(marker);
  });
});
```

edit: this couls work for you...

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', toggleBounce);
```

if you google that exact line, you get further pointers... good luck!

Comment: Neither worked for me, ive updated my question with my attempts. Please let me know if anymore detail would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Updated again. I didnt realise your code was supposed to be merged into the existing, not added at the end.

Comment: google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', toggleBounce); is in fact the way to add listeners to google maps api v3 objects