# Google Maps API get coordinates from predefined location

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am starting to work with google maps and have ran into something I can't seem to figure out. I have it setup so when I click on the map it creates a marker and I get the coordinates after that. This is handled through an onclick event. The issue I am having is if I click on a predefined location that google already has the onclick event doesn't fire. I don't see anyway to make the oncllck event fire so I can just get the address of the location clicked. Wondering what the trigger is to make an event happen when a user clicks on a location already on the map defined by google. This is using the web API.

Comment: Looks like this same question was asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16417600/how-can-i-capture-the-click-event-when-a-default-marker-place-is-clicked-on-goog seems like it's still unresolved though.