# How to remove native marker of google map

Tags: google-maps

I wonder if it's possible to remove native marker inside a google map.
For instance, every marker in orange, blue, subways markers, name of stores...

[native google map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2I65b.png)

Comment: related question: [I am not able to place markers on the places which is already marked by google with other symbols](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28186720/i-am-not-able-to-place-markers-on-the-places-which-is-already-marked-by-google-w)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change the style for suppressing the POI labels off eg:

```
      var myStyles =[
        {
            featureType: "poi",
            elementType: "labels",
            stylers: [
                  { visibility: "off" }
            ]
        }
    ];
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(initLat, initLng),
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
        mapTypeControl:false,
        scaleControl: true, 
        tilt: 0,
       styles: mlwStyles           
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it with [Google Maps APIs Styling Wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/).

It allows you to style pretty much everything on the map, from roads to water color.

To remove a native marker, just select its category and change the visibility to hidden.

After Styling the map, you can extract the json and use it in your application.