# Customize Google map V3 infowindow of defaults

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When you fully setup your Custom infowindow, you can set whatever content you wanted.

However, I am talking about the businesses that google map v3 initially added. How do I go about adjust the default infowindows of varies businesses? Like add pictures, stars OR HIDE them all?

Any examples would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

First Example showing that it can be adjusted
Booking.com:
[image]

Second Example to hide all of them:
Redfin.com
[image]

How to adjust for google map defaults? 
[image]

Please help me out! How do I do both? Hide & add pictures, stars etc to Default infowindow of google map v3?

Comment: You can't modify those, you can only hide the markers.

Comment: So if you go to booking.com, you can see that default businesses infowindow (star ratings, pictures etc)...  Redfin.com hides all the local businesses...
However on localhost, you can't seem to adjust any of the above two options... It only showing "Address, View on Google Map" options..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a click event when a user clicks a (business) place on the map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24234106/how-to-get-a-click-event-when-a-user-clicks-a-business-place-on-the-map)

Comment: I edited my original post a bit. Does my question make sense now?

Comment: Think its a valid questions... yet getting downvoted... ::sigh::

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the first example that you claim shows "it can be adjusted Booking.com", that is the way these business POI infowindows display in the Google Maps Javascript API v3.  The infowindows are different on Google Maps.

Comment: Okay so I might've messed up somewhere, how you adjust the business POI infowindows display? I think I can search better after understanding the term for it... Some reason mine doesn't show rating or pictures

Comment: As I said in my first comment, you can't adjust those, you can only make it so the markers (and thus the infowindows) don't appear on your map (like your redfin example).

Comment: I guess my confusion was that my site only shows as the third picture, but can't adjust it to make it like similar to redfin.. or the first one

Comment: I figured it out.... Edit src to google map resolves it... I don't believe it.. Thank you so much for your time

Comment: #1 and #3 are both defaults, the difference: #3 is a [signed-in map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/signedin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to compare would be to test the same places on those 3 map instances.

**1st example**: This is the default look. It can't be modified.

**2nd example**: You can use the styles to remove all or certain POI types on the map. See the [documentation here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeStyle). Also check the [Styled Maps Wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html) to help you build your styles.

**3rd example**: This is also the default look. If you need something else, then you will have to hide these POI (see above), create your own markers for the places you are interested in and create a custom [InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. Ya it was dumb, took me a while until I just noticed that src was throwing me off