# Google Maps JavaScript API - get a clicked POI name

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, click, angular-google-maps

Using version 3.20 and the 'signed_in' value it seems that clicking a POI (point of interest) triggers a click event (which was not the case in older version).

I was hoping there would be a way to find the place_id of the clicked POI or even just the name (perhaps by finding the open info window and pulling out the title content). Does anyone know of a way to do this, I can't see anything in the docs and using the nearby search isn't reliable enough unfortunatly.

Comment: You are right in that it triggers a click event on the map object. But there is still no *POI* overlay class on which you can listen to a click event.

Comment: yeah that seems to be the case, any ideas of a work around, I have feeling there might a way to detect the info window to read its title content which I can then use in conjunction with the nearby search to get the exact place_id

Comment: Sorry no idea. For sure there is no documented method to do that.

Comment: maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24234106/how-to-get-a-click-event-when-a-user-clicks-a-business-place-on-the-map ??

Comment: It seems that works if you don't use the signed_in param

Comment: I have same problem, finally what did you do?